# How update the UI from another thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I searched for a way to update UI from another thread, and found that the available approach is to use Handler.post(Runnable) as shown in the code snippet below:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Update UI
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                myHandler.post(updateRunnable);
            }).start();
        }
    };
}
```

Instead can't we use Handler.sendMessage and do the UI updates from main UI thread in handleMessage():

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what) {
                // Do logic here
            }
        }
    };


    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }).start();
        }
    };
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, however I'm quite confused with the above two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `runOnUiThread`. You can post a runnable which does the UI operation to main thread as follows,

```
public class Utils {

    public static void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable){
        final Handler UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        UIHandler .post(runnable);
    } 
}

Utils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // UI updation related code.
     }
});
```

Read more at:

> [android: update UI from another thread in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23547701/3653989)
>
> [Updating UI / runOnUiThread / final variables: How to write lean code that does UI updating when called from another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619942/3653989)
>
> https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at runOnUiThread. However can you please explain if the approach 1 in my post isn't the best approach? I have seen approach 1 being mentioned in few blogs.