# display api data with realm not working android studios

Tags: java, android, api, realm, okhttp

I am trying to use realm database to display my api data. I want to display the company name, however the data is saids it is inserted in the log but cant seem to display the data on the UI. Here is the code..
Any help would be greatly appreciated with this problem. The variables are at the top and the problem is when it hits on success, ive written the code "write to DB", but it doesnt display the data but tells me the data has been inserted.

```
 // Variables for the search input field and results TextViews.
    private EditText mCompanyInput;
    private TextView mTitleText;
    private TextView mDescriptionText;
    private TextView mOfficerText;
    private TextView mTitleText1;
    private TextView mDescriptionText1;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Request request;

    private String url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=";

    Button save;
    TextView log;
    Realm realm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCompanyInput = findViewById(R.id.companyInput);
        log = findViewById(R.id.log);
        mDescriptionText = findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        mOfficerText = findViewById(R.id.officerText);
        mTitleText1 = findViewById(R.id.titleText1);
        mTitleText = findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        mDescriptionText1 = findViewById(R.id.descriptionText1);


        save = findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        save.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        request = new Request.Builder().url(url).header("Authorization", "k6DNRbTp-AnQWn51JBz5VuPiTl8jv4_etdzoMyhf") .method("GET", null).build();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:"+url);

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
Log.i(TAG,response.body().string());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:"+response.code());
            }
        });

        writeToDB(mCompanyInput.getText().toString().trim(), (mDescriptionText.getText().toString().trim()));
        showData();
    }
    public void showData(){
        RealmResults<Company> guests = realm.where(Company.class).findAll();

// Use an iterator to invite all guests
        String op="";

        for (Company guest : guests) {
            op+=guest.getName();
            op+=guest.getAppointments();

        }

        log.setText(op);
    }

    public void writeToDB(final String mTitleText1, final String mDescriptionText1){

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Company user = new Company(mTitleText1, mDescriptionText1);
                bgRealm.insert(user);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                writeToDB(mCompanyInput.getText().toString().trim(), (mOfficerText.getText().toString().trim()));
                showData();
                // Transaction was a success.
                Log.v("Database", "Data Inserted");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
                Log.e("Database", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `writeToDB()` from the `onSuccess()` method? This will cause recursion and keep writing the same data into the realm. It's correct to call `showData()` from `onSuccess()`, but there's not much point calling it directly from `onClick()`.

I think your problem though is that you're trying to update the UI from a thread: it's called from an async transaction thread and not the main thread. See this answer (and there are others you can find easily once you know the problem: [Updating UI / runOnUiThread / final variables: How to write lean code that does UI updating when called from another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619942/updating-ui-runonuithread-final-variables-how-to-write-lean-code-that-does?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Let me know if that fixes the problem - and mark this as the answer if you're happy.